# Accept input as Json in html and send http request

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, input

I have a requirement to accept JSON String as input in one of the textfield such as input will be like ::

```
{"order":1}
```

On form submission i am trying to create request and send this input to http request

```
var body = ({"key" : input});

var request = {
                    method : 'POST',
                    url : '/xxx',
                    data : body,
                    headers : {
                        'Content-Type' : "application/json"
                    }
                };
                $http(request).success(function(response) {

                }).error(function(response) {

                });
```

but server responds with **400 Bad Request** as the body input is formed such as

```
"key": "{"order":"1"}"
```

whether as the server **expects** the input such as
 `"key": {"order":"1"}`

you can see that the `" "` at start and end of the json are extra appended as the type of the input is text, how can achieve the **expected**  format as mentioned above or any better approach. 
Please suggest.

Comment: I don't see `key` anywhere in your code. Your expected string is also malformed.

Comment: @MinusFour: Yes the key is representation for the actual `key:value` pair to be used, thanks i have  updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know where you get the variable 'input' but I'm assuming you are selecting it with jQuery somehow and then trying to get it's value by using val(). If that is the case, then what you are getting is a String and what you should be sending in the 'data' key in your ajax request should be a parsed JSON.

This should fix your problem:

```
data : JSON.parse(input)
```

Comment: The input from user in text box is JSON, i think `parse()` would again try to parse the Json back to Json. Anyways, i will try this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why `input` is a sting, but to overcome this, change `data : input,` to `data : JSON.parse(input),`